# Asp.net MVC action and view issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pagination

I am stuck in a weird situation. I have a controller action which is passed a category string. Then the action method matches the string in the database and collects the sub categories and products for it. Now, What I want is to achieve pagination for the products if they are greater than 10. The view is a strongly-typed one for Category Model

Following is the code for action method.

```
    public ActionResult Catalog(string id)
    {
        Category catalog = pe.Categories.Where(cat => cat.CategoryName == id).Single();
        return View(catalog);
    }
```

I have done pagination in my other project like following but in that case the collection was an IQueryable which can't be in the above case since its just for one category. Also, I am already passing an argument in the above function so how can i pass two.

```
    public ViewResult Index(int? page)
    {
        IQueryable<Album> albums = db.Albums.Include(a => a.Genre).Include(a => a.Artist).OrderBy(a => a.Title);
        int pageIndex = page ?? 1;
        return View(albums.ToPagedList(pageIndex, PageSize));
    }
```

Please tell me how will you tackle such scenario.

Comment: You are using Single() function after query. What is the collection you want to paginate?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları : Its the Category.Products collection. A single category with collection of products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a viewmodel to collect just the information that you want to show in your view.  In your selection logic, select into the viewmodel the top-level attributes from the category and the relevant parts of the association.  You can certainly have more than one parameter to the method.  Supply the extra parameters to the route values in your ActionLink or Form helper methods and  it should construct the Url properly to reference your action.  Note you will need to change the type of the model in the view as well to match that from the action.

```
public ActionResult Catalog(string id, int? page)
{
    page = page ?? 1;
    var category = pe.Categories.SingleOrDefault(cat => cat.CategoryName == id);
    var model = new CatalogViewModel
                {
                       ID = category.ID,
                       Name = category.CategoryName,
                       Subcategories = category.Subcategories,
                       Products = category.Products.ToPagedList( page, PageSize )
                };

    return View(model);
}
```

View (sample)

```
@if (Model.Products.Page < Model.Products.Pages)
{
    @Html.ActionLink( "Next",
                      "catalog",
                      new { id = Model.ID, page = Model.Products.Page + 1 } ) 
}
```

Comment: Getting this error :::: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[MvcMusicStore.Models.GenreAlbumView]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcMusicStore.Models.GenreAlbumView'

Comment: You need to realize the query before passing it to the view.  Call `SingleOrDefault` on it before passing it to the view.

Comment: I tried adding Single() but then it gave this error : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[MvcMusicStore.Models.Album] ToPagedList[Album](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvcMusicStore.Models.Album], Int32, Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: I had tried that too earlier :-) , sorry for disturbing you mate but i am bit new to MVC....It's something else :-(

Comment: I've fixed the example now.  First you find the **single** category, then transform it to the model.  You could do it in one statement by throwing a `ToList` after the `Where` and before the `Select`, then use the `SingleOrDefault` at the end, but the way I have it is simpler.  The problem, as you saw, was that the paged list call doesn't translate to SQL.  If the item/collection needs to be in memory before it's called.

Comment: This problem has been solved a bit. Just a minor glitter of getting the pagination. What should be the underlying type of Products in CatalogViewModel? Currently it's `IEnumerable<Products>`

Comment: Got that working i made it to the `PagedList.IPagedList<Products>`. Thanks mate....

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate your paged results before sending it to the view. I guess you have to take a page index parameter too.

```
public ActionResult Catalog(string id, int? pageIndex)
{
    Category catalog = pe.Categories.Where(cat => cat.CategoryName == id).Single();
    int pageIndex = page ?? 1;
    return View(catalog.Products.ToPagedList(pageIndex, PageSize));
}
```

You better use IEnumerable interface instead of IQueryable when you are doing operations in memory. Make your view strongly typed to `IEnumerable<Product>` and it should work.

If you are going to use any data from Category class in your view, you better create a ViewModel and put that data and your page result inside it.

Comment: I also need to display the subcategories from the categories class. So, I guess i need to make a new ViewModel for the entire thing. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Start from reading official docs - [Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Basically you can pass as many parameters to an action as you want, so you add `pageNumber` and use it.