# When to use ViewModel and when not in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

AFAIK, there are two ways of passing data to the view from controller : one being loosely typed(using ViewBag or ViewData), other being strongly-typed. Most recommend the latter because of strong compile-time checking.

In a dynamic web application, we come across scenarios when there is a requirement to pass multiple entities from the controller to the view. In that case, one can either pass a single entity as a model and rest in ViewBag dictionary. Or One can make an entirely new ViewModel class merging the various entities and then passing it to the view.

Recently, I encountered such an issue; I needed to pass a category model which had list of subcategories and products registered with it as properties. And then in the view, I needed to diplay the subcategories along with making sure that pagination occurs on products collection if they are more than 10. Therefore i couldn't use a strongly typed view for either Category Model or Product Model.

The Solution was presented by follow peers, [tvanfosson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12950/tvanfosson) and [Ufuk Hacıoğulları](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205859/ufuk-haciogullari)(Many thanks to both) in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027740/asp-net-mvc-action-and-view-issue/). And that is to use a ViewModel. I am still trying to understand and work on it and it seems to be the proper solution.

**Question** :  Is this a better way to handle such situations ? Also, when is it recommended to use ViewModel and when to bypass it in favour ViewBag & a Model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one and only purpose of a Viewmodel class is to contain (strongly typed) data to be sent to a view by an action method.

So as the answers in your referred question suggest create a Viewmodel class which contains properties for all the data you need in your view.

The advantage of Viewbag usage is that you don't have the overhead to create a separate class.
The disadvantage is that you don't have compile time type checking and intellisense available.

Comment: Really great answer mate. You seem to have used 0% irrelevant words. Thanks !!